# How to read a Javascript-based webpage from octave?

Tags: javascript, octave

I'm downloading a webpage from an Octave script and storing it with urlwrite. Problem is that the webpage is not "readable HTML", but instead a set of scripts which build the (text) page on the browser. urlread, of course, yields the same result.

How can I read the actual webpage that I see in the browser? Don't know of any method to run JS from Octave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved under Linux with `xdotool`. A 'system' call would open a chrome window with the webpage to download, then 'xdotool' would focus on that window, send a Ctrl-U to open the source (this is the real content), send Ctrl-A and Ctrl-C to copy all that, then paste with `xsel` and save the html file. It means automating the manual process, and it worked pretty well. Couldn't find a 'clean' solution.

Here's an [example](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?key=copiar) of a page fitting this formatting.